# SPARQL group by only one variable

Tags: group-by, sparql, rdf

I am trying to list the largest lake in each country in the world for a school exercise. I am using [this dbpedia endpoint](http://dbpedia.org/sparql). Here is what i have:

```
select ?country (MAX(?area) AS ?maxarea)
where {
 ?lake rdfs:label ?label .
 ?lake rdf:type dbo:Lake .
 ?lake dbo:areaTotal ?area .
 ?lake dbo:country ?country .
 FILTER (lang(?label) = 'en') .
}
group by ?country
```

I get the country and the area of its largest lake which is the desired result but without the name of the lake. I just want to list the name of the lake in the table. So when I add ?label to the select, it complains that

> Variable ?label is used in the result set outside aggregate and not mentioned in GROUP BY clause

If I add the ?label to GROUP BY, then it groups with ?country and ?label which it tries to get the max of. This results in listing all the possible lakes(when it groups by country and by lake, each group has one element, because country lake combination is always unique) which is not what I want.

I tried to solve this by using different kinds of joins and subqueries to no avail. Also SAMPLE doesn't work, because it just picks a random lake from the country instead of the largest lake. **To make it clear, I am not asking for the answer but I am asking if there is a possible way to list a variable without adding to GROUP BY.**

Comment: What about using `min(?label)` or `max(?label)` ? Both should not return a random label but apply lexicographic sorting.

Comment: Alternatively - with the same result - you could pick a fixed label for each lake in a sub-query using `order by` and `limit 1` and then use `sample(?label)`. But the result would be the same.

Comment: And in general, either you `select` the variable wrapped in an aggregate function or it has to be added to the `group by`

Comment: using min(?label) or max(?label) prints out random lakes and not the correct ones.

Comment: `And in general, either you select the variable wrapped in an aggregate function or it has to be added to the group by`, If this is the official specification, post it as an answer with the explanation and I will accept it.

Answer (score 2):

**This answer doesn't really answer my original question which is if I can select a variable without using it in the GROUP BY. As far as I understand, I can list it with a subquery but I can't just have a variable without using it in the GROUP BY.**

I solved the exercise question using a subquery like this:

```
select ?country ?area ?lake
where {
    ?lake rdfs:label ?label .
    ?lake rdf:type dbo:Lake .
    ?lake dbo:areaTotal ?area .
    ?lake dbo:country ?country .
    ?country rdf:type dbo:Country .
    FILTER (lang(?label) = 'en') .
    FILTER(?maxarea = ?area)
    {
        select ?country (MAX(?area) AS ?maxarea)
        where {
            ?lake rdfs:label ?label .
            ?lake rdf:type dbo:Lake .
            ?lake dbo:areaTotal ?area .
            ?lake dbo:country ?country .
            ?country rdf:type dbo:Country .
            FILTER (lang(?label) = 'en') .
        }
        group by ?country
    }
}
```

I added a ?country rdf:type dbo:country check to remove some regions like "Newark Basin".

Comment: Ah, now that I re-read your question and understood the problem. Yes, your solution is the typical procedure how to solve it.

Comment: By the way, I wouldn't rely that much on the data quality. For example, the result for Germany is for sure wrong, looks like some issue with the DBpedia extractor from the Wikipedia entry.

Comment: @lamyarus, FYI: [Largest cities per country on Wikidata](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Wikidata:SPARQL_query_service/queries/examples#Largest_cities_per_country).

Comment: Does this query seem a little off? Assuming there are two lakes in different countries with the same area, then this would return both lakes (in different countries). So another `filter` in the outer `select` should be necessary for country: `filter(?countryOuter = ?countryInner)`.